# Java - Long List ERROR : incompatible types

Tags: java, long-integer

I'm working on this code, that use big numbers :

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double max = 1e+15;
        List<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        sum.add(1);
        long aux = 0;
        for(long i = 1;i<max;i++){
            sum.add(sum.get(i-1)+scomponi(sum.get(i-1),aux));  
            if(i+1==1e+7 || i+1==1e+8 || i+1==1e+9 || i+1 == 1e+10 || i+1 == 1e+10 || i+1==1e+11 || i+1==1e+12 || i+1==1e+13 || i+1==1e+14)
                System.out.println(i+1+"-imo -> "+sum.get(i));  
        }
        System.out.println(sum.get(sum.size()-1)); 
    }    


    public static Long scomponi(Long num,Long tot) {
        while (num > 0) {
            Long digit = num % 10;
            tot += digit;
            num /= 10;
        }
        return tot;
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to find a solution for this error :

[image: error]

What it means? I'm not really good in java, but this is so simple code, what's wrong?

Comment: Like this error told you, you are using a long instead of an int in the get method. This mean that Java would need to truncate your long when the value will be higher than the int limit. So it told you there is an error

Comment: 1e+15 >>> 2147483647 .. I can't use int so I cant use Lists..Thnak you

Comment: Array are Integer based to I believe ;) So you would need to find some tricks (like multiple Lists). But why so much ? The memory would be enough ?

Comment: Nope, if I use a long wariable it will takes too much time..Arrays ll be also too big .. sheet :))

Comment: Then, what do you want to do ? Try to simply loop on every long value, you will see the problem ;)

Comment: you need to try `int integer= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(longVariable));`   or extend the signature to`sum.add(sum.get(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i)-1))+scomponi(sum.get(i-1),aux));` *its worth giving a shot* ;)

Comment: Yes I googled I found solutions, @AsteriskNinja I saw that but for this algorithm is not good. I ve to think to another alog becouse this one takes too much times..

Comment: @AxelH I've to found another algorithm for this problem..

Comment: You could simply use a file to store the result, you only need the previous value in your code. But the loop while still took a lot of time ;)

Comment: @AxelH but sum+=scomponi(sum) means I ve to use the previous result, so I have to go into the file 1e+15 times, to get it and then to save the new value..

Comment: Look at my answer ;) you always take the last one, keep it in a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists in Java are `int`-indexed, as you can see in the javadoc of [`List.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)), and you're trying to get elements by a `long` index.

If you need lists bigger than the integer range, you need another data structure that supports that, you cannot use `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Like janos said, you can't use long index in a List. But from your code, you don't need the list, you only use the last value calculated.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    double max = 1e+15;
    long last = 1;
    long aux = 0;
    for(long i = 1;i<max;i++){
        last += scomponi(last,aux);
        if(i+1==1e+7 || i+1==1e+8 || i+1==1e+9 || i+1 == 1e+10 || i+1 == 1e+10 || i+1==1e+11 || i+1==1e+12 || i+1==1e+13 || i+1==1e+14)
            System.out.println(i+1+"-imo -> "+last);
    }
    System.out.println(last);
}
```

If you really want to keep every values, you could store those into a file but from what I see, you don't need those.

Of couse, the loop will take some time ;)